# Can't solve rewrite map and htaccess issue. Something wrong with condition?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know this has to be something trivial I am missing. But I am going on a week here without any luck.

Say a user visits my old website with his username to get to his dashboard.

for example

```
foobar.example.com
```

would direct the visitor to

```
example.com/dashboard/12345
```

where 12345 is the userid for foobar user.

This has been working for the longest time.

However, now I moved everyone to a new server, new software and new user id's

And I have this htaccess setup

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newexample.com/profile/${zq3:$1|0} [L]
```

The zq3 usermap query simply does ...

```
RewriteMap zq3 "dbd:SELECT newuserid FROM rewrite_map WHERE username = %s"
```

The query works fine. However for some reason, when the map query is called it always returns 0 which is the if not found return this .

I believe something is wrong with the rewrite rule where it is not passing the username properly.

Any help would be appreciated. Oh Also, would like to ignore www if that is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Might be like this?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newexample.com/profile/${zq3:%1|0} [L]
```

**%1** is the first match from RewriteCond, not **$1** as it's the first match from RewriteRule.

Please see: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#regex